# What language requires no external runtime and can run as a service (no GUI)

Tags: programming-languages, service

I'm a longtime web developer. (With some minor experience using AutoIT & some time messing with Android.)

Have now been asked to write a relatively simple script for distribution.

Requirements:

- No GUI. checks/sets some registry keys in Win, the dev folder in Max/*nix.
- It must be able to run as a service.
- It must NOT require a runtime environment. The client has had bad experience with Java and .NET, and is scared of relying on AIR (which would've been my first thought). The gist of the issue is people not being willing or able to download these environments - but it's non negotiable, whether or not it's logical.
- Smaller is better, when it comes to the output.

Does the language I need exist?

As an aside, I understand that this is supposed to complement some other program which DOES have a GUI, and which already exists in C++. This need not be in the same language.

I am willing to learn a new language for this objective, if need be.
If the perfect language does not exist, can software be written in Python, and then exported somehow to meet these requirements (I'd be happier to learn Python than C's if possible).
Should I use AutoIT and somehow have an installer make the exe run as a service? (Have not found anything that made sense to my noob brain while Googling.)

Also, any tips or heads-up from the experienced dev would be appreciated.

---

EDIT: "No Runtime Environment (RE)" was to exclude a 15+ MB's dependency on a 15 line script.
What I meant is a language that will pretty much run on most computers as is.

I understand that every language must have the language installed in order to be run, which perforce is an RE, besides the operating system on which that RE is installed.
I also understand the groan when someone installs a 30KB app, and is told that the computer must download a 30MB dependency (.NET, JAVA, AIR..)
And Pye2exe's method of including the 10MB of Python with the file is no better.

Comment: What platform/OS is this supposed to run on? Different OSes will have different runtime environments installed.

Comment: Technically, unless you implement libc yourself or statically link a version of it that doesn't require an OS, you have a runtime dependency (in this case on the OS runtime libraries).

Comment: This is a stealth Microsoft question.  It should be in the tags.

Comment: @tchrist, except that he also mentioned Linux and OS X, as well.

Comment: @Michael: Whoops, sorry. I think then that the *easiest* solution would be to write a non-shell script; that is, a perl script or a python script.  The shell is too full of subtle platform dependencies. Perl is on more platforms by default than Python, but you still probably want to run some sort of bundler for Microsoft systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by others all programs have dependencies on a runtime environment being at least the OS. However I understand that adding extra code to the runtime environment can cause problems if the users do not update their machines as required.

There is always a risk that you code will use something that a user has not updated e.g. they have Windows XP without a service pack and you require something newer.

I think there are several possible solutions

1) as  @Michael Aaron Safyan says use a batch command - I think you will be able to do this in Unix but windows batch might be too restrictive for your requirments

2) Write the application in C/C++ with static libraries then the install should just be the code you have and it should run.You will have to look in as to how to set up a service but I think a Windows installer or in OSX a shell script will do this. (There are other languages that can be compiled into a single executable)

3) For Unix python and perl are normally installed in /usr/bin but might be an old version - so this is a possiblility

4) provide an installer which installes your app and the runtime. This is doable with Windows and .Net Microsoft supply then .Net runtime as a [redistributable package](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569263), python can be built inro a plain windows execuable using [pyexe](http://www.py2exe.org/).

Comment: Thanks. 1. Batch commands are not enough, though the idea is good.

Comment: 2. How do I do that? When I build in Visual Studio it requires .NET? Also, all of the registry related classes Ive found requires .NET or MFC or ATL - where do I find the classes (or a tutorial)? 3. & 4. Thanks a lot!! Will look into Python as a solution as well. Is it better to just use python with pye2exe, or should I try to learn how to do it in C/C++? Also, do you know if there is a simple way to use an installer to turn a regular .exe into a service?

Comment: These should be separate questions - VS can build plain C/c++ - MSDN for tutorials ad also for how to build a service. Python is easier to learn is the only recommendation I have over C++

Answer (score 2):

I think Go language (cross-)compiles to a single static binary with no runtime dependency.

2018 welcomes you. =)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are writing a standalone binary (one which statically links its own libc and can be run without an OS), you will technically have a runtime dependency (e.g. on the various OS libraries such as `libc.so` on Linux, `libSystem.dylib` on Mac OS X, and `msvcrt.dll` on Windows). Whoever has asked you to do this has an unfounded fear of runtime dependencies. The whole point of OSes are to provide a runtime environment with common functionality already implemented to make life much simpler for programmers. To truly have no runtime dependencies, you would pretty much be going back to the stone age. There is no reason that you cannot use C++, Java, Python, or pretty much any other standard programming language to accomplish your task. Realistically, your solution on Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X may need to be different. If the task is simple enough, you may even be able to use BASH script on UNIX (Mac OS X and Linux) and a simple BATCH script on Windows. Note that those do have runtime dependencies (the BASH and BATCH interpreters, respectively) but, again, these fears are entirely unfounded and utterly ridiculous. It would probably be more helpful to describe the particular task rather than how to accomplish the unspecified task with absurd constraints.

Comment: Understood. The point was not to avoid a RE entirely, but rather to avoid a 25MB dependency for a script that is five lines. Which is what happens when I sent him code that I wrote in Visual Studio 2010. I have Java programs that do not run because of JRE issues, and cannot install certain software on my laptop because it doesn't have room for .NET v4, and Python scripts need a Python install on Windows, which is not for the average user - so I think these fears are founded.  What he really means is - most software downloaded from the net run even without .NET or JRE. How?

Answer (score 0):

- Clisp
- http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/
- Bash
- Perl

All of the above can be installed as just a few files.

Windows these days comes with quite a lot of built-in scripting options (Scripting host, PowerShell).

The question is not "what programming language can do this", but rather "what implementations are there". You're full of options - just try googling the various scripting options available to you.

Comment: The OP wants no installation separate to his own.

Comment: @Mark try reading either the question or the answer properly.

Comment: Op says " not being willing or able to download these environments" amd answer says "All of the above can be installed as just a few files."

Comment: @Mark: I said "read" not "copy-and-paste". That implies some understanding, and also reading all of the way to the end.

Comment: I had not known much about PowerShell. While it's Win XP SP3+ only, it stands as something to research more if needed.

Comment: @SamGoody - I assume you've thought about Scripting Host?

Answer (score 0):

[Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), [Go](https://go.dev/) and [Kotlin/Native](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/native-overview.html) all compile to a single executable, pretty much for any target. There's also [bflat](https://github.com/bflattened/bflat) which also produces a single executable from C# code.

If you want it to be as small as possible, you probably are looking at writing C/C++ and compiling it statically (which I would not recommend).

If the target system has a shell like bash/zsh you can also write a shell script. Same for Windows, you might be able to just write a PowerShell or Batch script.